# Remove BETA versions after update to 1.0.0 of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This may sound like a really silly question, but I've searched and can't find any information regarding it, but once I've installed V1.0.0 of Android Studio, can I safely remove any previous Beta version?

I only ask because it imported settings from a previous version I had. I'm assuming that the new version will save it's own config once it's imported data, but I just want to make sure, because it took me ages to set it up originally, and I'd hate to lose it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are safe.

You probably know that it's Idea under the hood? I never had problems upgrading from different versions (never lost any settings), and that's for Idea Ultimate & Community as well as for AS.

I think I had > 5 different versions of AS in the last few months, and I've always removed the previous version once the new version proved to be stable.

As a side note - you know that you can export / import your settings?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Yes I did know about manual importing, but it was happy enough to do it upon start up, so left as is. I will however, backup my settings. Just in case ;) Cheers.